# Don't show wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, web, wordpress-theming

I work with wordpress farsi.I am early in wordpress and site. I install theme 2014 on it. In server all thing is OK. But when i see site from out of server, i just see text and that don't show theme of site. when i see console of browser i see this errors:

```
genericons.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
style.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
rtl.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
jquery.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
jquery-migrate.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
skip-link-focus-fix.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
functions.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
wp-embed.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
wp-emoji-release.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

When i change `Phpmyadmin->my database->wp_options->siteurl and home` address frome `http://localhost` to `http://`, in out of server was OK. But now i can not loggin to wp-admin in server.

What must i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change `Phpmyadmin->my database->wp_options->siteurl` to `YourSiteAdrress` not to `http://`.